# Eclipse Gradle Dependencies not listed

Tags: java, android, eclipse, gradle

I'm new to gradle.  I'm importing an existing project that I've never worked on before.  When I do a gradle project import in eclipse, the project "Gradle Dependencies" list is empty:

[image]

I've tried multiple variations of "Refresh XXX" from the project gradle context menu.  I've tried removing and re-importing the project in eclipse.  I've tried gradle cleanEclipse cleanEclipseWtp eclipse eclipseWtp.

I'm out of ideas.  why might eclipse not be picking up my dependencies.  Shouldn't it also automatically pick up src/main/java as a project source directory?

=== ***update 1*** ===

This appears to be related to the plugins being loaded in build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'
```

If I substitute

```
apply plugin: 'java'
```

in place of

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

The dependencies are loaded correctly.

I can't get the dependencies to be recognized in eclipse when using the 'com.android.application' plugin.

=== ***update 2*** ===

gradle eclipse doesn't seem to add any of my gradle dependencies to my classpath:

[image]

=== ***update 3*** ===

Looks like there's an open [github issue](https://github.com/Nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/issues/148) for gradle eclipse android project support.

Comment: Just use the eclipse-wtp gradle plugin to generate the eclipse files and the import the project in eclipse with the "Import existing project" feature.

Comment: Just tried that.  Now the "Gradle Dependencies" item is completely missing.

Comment: Of course it is. Now the project is a regular Eclipse one. If you can find your dependencies in the "Referenced libraries" tab then you're good to go :)

Comment: Well that won't work.  I want the project dependencies to continue to be managed by gradle.

I'm used to maven.  Add a <dependency>, refresh the project, it shows up under "Maven Dependencies."  That's what I'm looking for with gradle.

Comment: But your project dependencies are managed by Gradle. After you modify the gradle build file and add or remove stuff, just regenerate the eclipse project files with "gradle eclipse", hit f5 in Eclipse on your project and you're done.

Comment: Fair enough.  Still, I had no referenced libraries.  See update 2.